# Javascript scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, scope

I have a script with a similar structure to this

```
$(function(){

  var someVariable;

  function doSomething(){
      //here
  }

  $('#something').click(function(){
      //here
  })

});
```

My question is;

From the doSomething function, and the click handler
how can I access the someVariable without passing it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it without any special syntax. `someVariable` is available in closure scope of `doSomething`.

[Read more on JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: strange, for some reason it was not working before :/ will accept asap (due to link to extra resources)

Comment: In the question's code, `doSomething` isn't used to create a closure, though the anonymous function passed to the click handler is.

Comment: Closure can be confusing. It's also known as "lexical scope" which I think is more intuitive to understand. What's in scope can be determined purely but looking at the source and seeing what encloses your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use it. No need for `this`.

```
$(function(){
    var someVariable = 3;
    function doSomething(){
        alert(someVariable);
    }
});
```

Comment: An inner function automatically has access to the variables defined in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

When `ECMA- / Javascript` methods are invoked (called), several things happen. To make a long story short, when a function is called a such called **Activation object** is created for that function. In that object you'll find things like **arguments**, **local variables and function declarations** and the **arguments object**. The "Context" of the invoked function has a `[[Scope]]` property. That is the place where all **parent context's** are stored when the function is invoked.

That concept (which I pretty much shrinked together here) is the basic thing to have **closures**. That means if you call `doSomething()` in your example, the function will copy the parent Context into it's `[[Scope]]`, which includes `someVariable`. The anonymous function from your event listener does the same thing, both methods share **the same scope**.

---

Short answer: You can just use and access `someVariable` in all of methods.